# linux script to move files in directories with data

Tags: linux, bash, shell, cron, jobs

I'm using `freeradius` with `daloradius` appliance.
Now there are lots of routers connected to this radius server and the database and log files are growing too much.

The log files from `freeradius` are saved on:

```
/radacct/xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/detail-20150404
```

`xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx` are differents IP clients, so there are lots of folders and lots of files inside these folders.

I can add this directory to rotate log because the file detail-TODAY can't be modified during the day and can be accessible all the 24h.

So I'm asking for:

A script to move `/radacct/xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/detail-yyyymmdd` to a new folder `/radacct_old/xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/detail-yyyymmdd`.

We have to move all files **except** where `yyyymmdd` is the current date (date when the script is executed).
After this I can rotate log `radacct_old` or just add to zip `radacct_old_yyyymmdd`.

I'm planning to do this job every week or so.

What’s the best way do you suggest?

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
function move {
    today=$(date +%Y%m%d)
    file="${1#/radacct/}"
    ip="${file%%/*}"
    name="${file##*/}"
    if [[ ! $name =~ detail-$today ]]; then
        dir="/radacct_old/$ip"
        [ -d "${dir}" ] || mkdir "${dir}"            
        mv "${1}" "${dir}/${name}"
    fi
}
export -f move

find /radacct -type d -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2 -name '*detail*' -exec bash -c 'move "$0"' {} \;
```

Beware this is untested, you will certainly be able to fill the gaps. I will test it out and debug later if you can't seem to make it work. Post when you have further questions.

Explanation: generally the script looks for all directories of the required format and moves them (last two lines) by calling a function (beginning).

**Move function**

- `today=$(date +%Y%m%d)` constructs the date in the required format.
- `file="${1#/radacct/}"` remove leading directory name from the directory we found using `find`.
- `ip="${file%%/*}"` extract the ip address.
- `name="${file##*/}"` extract the dir name.
- `if [[ ! $name =~ detail-$today ]]; then` if dir name is from today.
- `dir="/radacct_old/$ip"` construct target directory.
- `[ -d "${dir}" ] || mkdir "${dir}"` create it if it doesn't exist.
- `mv "${1}" "${dir}/${name}"` move the dir to the new location.
- `export -f move` export the function so it can be called in subshell

**Find function**

- `find /radacct` look in `/radacct` dir
- `-type d -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2` look for dirs in dirs.
- `-name '*detail*'` which contain the word detail.
- `-exec bash -c 'move "$0"' {} \;` and execute the move function, supplying the name of the dir as argument.

Note that I will add more details and test it later today.

To perform this weekly, use a [cron](/questions/tagged/cron) job.

Comment: hi, tanks for the script and sorry the delay. I'm really new on Linux and scripts. I create a file scmove2.sh, give permisions to execute, copy your lines and execute "sh scmove2.sh" but i got this errors: 3: function: not found, 12: [[: not found and 13: Syntax error: "}" unexpected. Thanks.

Comment: @OscarJofre Try to add `#!/bin/bash` as the first line of your `scmove2.sh`. Use [tag:bash] for the job, not [tag:sh] as this code won't work using `sh`. So either add the line or execute it using `bash scmove2.sh`.

Comment: how the script looks in case of sh?